# Magento 2 : Upgrade from 2.0.2 to 2.1.2 already exist error

Tags: magento2, upgrade

My current **magento version is 2.0.2**. In this version i override default module by putting that module inside `app/code/Magento` directory Ex. app/code/Magento/Theme and everything work fine.

Now i upgrade magento from `2.0.2` to `2.1.2`

After upgrade it display following error :

> Autoload error: Module `Magento_Theme` from `{magento root}\app\code\Magento\Theme` has been already defined in `{magento root}/vendor/magento/module-theme`.

If i remove theme folder it solve my error.But i can't remove because i already done changes in that.

Comment: inside theme folder there is regestraion.php error if i remove this file error solved but my changes can't override

Comment: i already done all this but nothing work

Comment: remove from vendor folder, remove dependency from composer.json run upgrade command and compile

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload modules in magento2 like that. If it worked in 2.0.2, it was a bug.

Comment: Cool, Can you please explain a bit deeper, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed Magento 2.0.2 from GitHub. 
But when you try to upgrade it to 2.1.2 via the wizard in the Admin Panel.
This features only using for version installed when download from Magento Download Page - https://magento.com/tech-resources/download (or via composer, not GitHub).

So it duplicates component and return your errors.

Comment: I try to upgrade via composer and it already upgrdaed but after that it display this error

Comment: Because, you installed Github version and you only update via git not composer